# Load certain pages in a modal box on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have built a simple modal using jQuery which takes a url and then loads it using the ajax method and inserts the response html into a div I display on the screen in the design of a modal box. Simple stuff!

However these pages are actual urls e.g. `domain.com/posts/add` and can be accessed directly via the browser and not just clicking a link within the app. I would prefer that they be displayed in modal at all times even if the user types the url into the address bar. Currently I make it so that if the request IS NOT Ajax then redirect them to the homepage or show a 404 to prevent this from happening.

I would prefer to load these pages in the modal should the user access them directly via HTTP in the same way that the Chrome store does this e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia

How would I do this though? Without having to do some really messy javascript? Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Please note that this should work like a proper app in that it allows the user to use the back and forth buttons and the modal should appear and disappear

As for the modal code I use...

It is really simple and this is an example of how it looks (note mine is more robust than this, code purely for example of simplicity)

```
$('.ajax-link').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault;

$.ajax({

url: $(this).attr('href'),
success: function(response) {
$('<div id="modal">' + response + '</div>').appendTo('body');
}
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead.

Second, if you are using full urls from another domain, its most likely due to security issues as mentioned in the link above:

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Unless you are using `JSONP`, which I doubt you are.

Comment: What? Who said another domain :/ I said how can I make it so that pages that I normally load into a modal using AJAX also load into a modal when they are directly accessed via the url as HTTP request.

Comment: You did, when you put full url in your question.

Comment: The full url is because the user can get to the page loaded in the modal at a url e.g. it's an actual page accessible via HTTP as well as XMLHttp which was my point! I never said it was on another domain!

Comment: So you're saying that when someone enters in a full url in the browser, you only want the modal to view it?

Comment: YES! The obvious problem is what to show behind the modal, as in the Chrome store example they show the index page and then just load in the details in the modal anyways so it's easier. BUT I could just show my own index page e.g. https://www.facebook.com/events/create see how it loads a modal (if you use facebook) just looking for some ideas of best way to develop this.

Comment: Then every page that you are loading the modal with needs to have some sort of way of gathering the URL entered in the browser.  You would even possibly use querystrings for this, like this `domain.com/modal?url=/myurl.html` or a hash, like this: `domain.com/modal#/myurl.html` then parse your `.load/.get()` function accordingly.

Comment: are you using any server side language with this?

Comment: Yeah it's built in ASP.NET MVC and my plan so far is in the get method for the view is to check if its XMLHttp and then display a different page if not and then some tell the ORIGINAL view to load inside a modal on load. Not quite sure how best to do that though.

Comment: Your modal should always be loading one single script/url then.  like this, `/httprequest.aspx?url=...`

Answer (score 0):

Okies figured out how to do this:

It requires an MVC framework to do this properly IMO as I can't see how it's possible with old-fashioned pages due to their static nature, but basically the idea is that your views must inherit from other views so for example:

You have two views a list of people and form for adding people. However these both inherit from another view such as list or modal so that when the user requests the add person using HTTP it loads the form but using the inherited list so it creates the desired effect. So effectively the logic is all done in the controller.

An great article on inheritance here: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/view-inheritance-in-cakephp for CakePHP which is another framework I use.

Hopefully that makes sense to others wanting to try this out, but just tried it out and it works like a treat!

**UPDATE: After thinking about this some more, I've decided that the inheritance is far more complicated than need be and doesn't fully replicate the modal as getting the modal to appear at the bottom of the DOM requires... lots of complex structure in the views!**

**My alternative plan is to do the XMLHttp check in the controller and if it's not then load in the list view instead of the form BUT with a query string or something like JSON that then uses AJAX to load in the intended view from the url. This might sound like a double request for the same page you should of got but it does the job.**

**The only issue is that you can't send through BOTH the view and JSON telling it to load in the other view into a modal... Any ideas how to do that? other than passing a query string?**

---

**UPDATE: 2**

**The more I think about it, it DOES seem better to do the inheritance as it's not actually possible to do it how I though using the JSON as far as I can tell...**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a hashtag or url variable to denote how the page should load?  From what I see in Google Chrome all the modal windows are in the detail subdirectory while the other areas are category or search. That window location probably denotes how the page is displayed.